# Duplicate value for resource attr/textSize with Config

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, wearables

[image: Screenshot]
I add the wear module into the existing application, and provide the support of another module (that handles the Auth and Network task). When we build, gradle shows the following error:

> duplicate resource attr/textSize with Config.

Our Android Wear dependencies:

1. compile 'com.android.support:wear:27.0.0'
2. api project(':core')// Network and Encryption related module
3. provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.1.0'
4. compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.1.0'

If we remove the core module its not showing any error,

Comment: can you share your code snippet

Comment: Only MainActivity present in wearable(no Code is added till now) Just adding the New Module and Provide the support for Core module

Comment: have you solve this issue @ Abhishek      i am also facing this issue on C:\Users\Dhaval\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\47a04e297b3510c6351cd7d548a00d46\jetified-scatter-piechart-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:3:5-392: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/textSize' with config ''

Comment: @RameshBhati , I'am facing same issue did you win?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you might want to do is to make sure that all modules 
are on the same build tools and depend the same libraries versions.
Second, make sure that transitive dependencies are on the same versions.
Gradle usally says warning that the different versions of lib are found, 
ex. support percent, recycler and so on.
Next thing that might help is to update the libraries versions to the newest ones, 
transitive dependencies also.
If any of those did not help, only thing that left is to try to find out from where the conflicting attribute is, and then try to find out the solution (play with library versions eg).